# Image file writes with double the size of actual

Tags: java, tiff, graphics2d, javax.imageio

I'm trying to read a multi page tiff and blackout some content and then write it again.

Code :-

```
public void blackOut(File file, File outputTiff, String compressionType) throws IOException
    {
        ImageReader reader = getImageReader(file);
        int pageCount = reader.getNumImages(true);

        Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName(TIFF_FORMAT);
        if (!writers.hasNext())
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(JAI_IMAGE_WRITER_MESSAGE);
        }
        ImageWriter writer = writers.next();

        TIFFImageWriteParam tiffWriteParam = new TIFFImageWriteParam(Locale.US);

        if (compressionType != null)
        {
            tiffWriteParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
            tiffWriteParam.setCompressionType(compressionType);
        }

        IIOMetadata streamMetadata = writer.getDefaultStreamMetadata(tiffWriteParam);

        try (ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(outputTiff))
        {
            writer.setOutput(ios);

            int dpiX = 300;
            int dpiY = 300;

            for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++)
            {
                BufferedImage bufferedImage = reader.read(i);

                Graphics2D g2d = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
                g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
                g2d.fillRect(X, Y, Width, Height);
                g2d.dispose();

                IIOImage iioImage = new IIOImage(bufferedImage, null, null);

                ImageTypeSpecifier imageType = ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromRenderedImage(iioImage.getRenderedImage());
                ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
                IIOMetadata imageMetadata = writer.getDefaultImageMetadata(imageType, param);
                imageMetadata = setDPIViaAPI(imageMetadata, dpiX, dpiY);
                iioImage.setMetadata(imageMetadata);

                if (i == 0)
                {
                    IIOImage firstIioImage = iioImage;
                    writer.write(streamMetadata, firstIioImage, tiffWriteParam);
                }
                else
                {
                    writer.writeInsert(i, iioImage, tiffWriteParam);
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            writer.dispose();
        }

    }

private static IIOMetadata setDPIViaAPI(IIOMetadata imageMetadata, int dpiX, int dpiY)
            throws IIOInvalidTreeException
    {
        // Derive the TIFFDirectory from the metadata.
        TIFFDirectory dir = TIFFDirectory.createFromMetadata(imageMetadata);

        // Get {X,Y}Resolution tags.
        BaselineTIFFTagSet base = BaselineTIFFTagSet.getInstance();
        TIFFTag tagXRes = base.getTag(BaselineTIFFTagSet.TAG_X_RESOLUTION);
        TIFFTag tagYRes = base.getTag(BaselineTIFFTagSet.TAG_Y_RESOLUTION);

        // Create {X,Y}Resolution fields.
        TIFFField fieldXRes = new TIFFField(tagXRes, TIFFTag.TIFF_RATIONAL,
                1, new long[][] {{dpiX, 1}});
        TIFFField fieldYRes = new TIFFField(tagYRes, TIFFTag.TIFF_RATIONAL,
                1, new long[][] {{dpiY, 1}});

        // Append {X,Y}Resolution fields to directory.
        dir.addTIFFField(fieldXRes);
        dir.addTIFFField(fieldYRes);

        // Convert to metadata object.
        IIOMetadata metadata = dir.getAsMetadata();

        // Add other metadata.
        IIOMetadataNode root = new IIOMetadataNode("javax_imageio_1.0");
        IIOMetadataNode horiz = new IIOMetadataNode("HorizontalPixelSize");
        horiz.setAttribute("value", Double.toString(25.4f / dpiX));
        IIOMetadataNode vert = new IIOMetadataNode("VerticalPixelSize");
        vert.setAttribute("value", Double.toString(25.4f / dpiY));
        IIOMetadataNode dim = new IIOMetadataNode("Dimension");
        dim.appendChild(horiz);
        dim.appendChild(vert);
        root.appendChild(dim);
        metadata.mergeTree("javax_imageio_1.0", root);

        return metadata;
    }
```

while writing the file again I'm getting the file double (sometimes triple) the size of actual and that too after applying the compression 'LZW'.

Any way that I can get the same file size as previous?

Thanks.

Comment: @Abra Because its the same image I'm writing. and there is not much change in the files.

Comment: @Abra I've tried without changing anything in image...but got the same result. 1.50 MB file get to 7 MB.

Comment: There are various reasons why your file may become larger, the most likely situation here is that you change the compression from the original to something less efficient. What is the compression of your original file? My guess it's some CCITT b/w, or JPEG compression. Maybe you could rework your code to a full runnable program and link the input file? That would help a lot for understanding the problem.